# Python Check if a Minute has passed

Tags: python

Im running part of a script just once per minute and came up with this:

```
def minutePassed(oldminute):
    currentminute = time.gmtime()[4]

    if ((currentminute - oldminute) >= 1) or (oldminute == 59 and currentminute >= 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Problem here is that if the minute is 59 it runs everytime until its past that time - its not much of a bother performance wise for me. But I still dont like it happening!

I thought of something like this now:

```
def minutePassed(oldminute):
    currentminute = time.gmtime()[4]

    if ((currentminute - oldminute) >= 1) or (oldminute == 59 and currentminute >= 0 and ran == false):
        ran = True
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then on another part of the script I turn ran false again when the minute is != 59 and the variable isnt already false - but that seems crude?

On another note - is there any other way to check if a minute has passed? Maybe im making things complicated ...

Edit: Maybe I was not clear enough:

1. Run only ONCE per minute.
2. Execution time varies by many seconds but takes less then 30s.

Im looking at timedelta now.

Comment: No time to write up a full answer (someone else can have it), but you should be using `datetime.timedelta`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Wow .. timedelta - this seems to be it! Not having seen that before makes me feel bad!

Answer (score 24):

Don't work with minutes like that; if the time is, for example, 00:00:59, your code will believe a minute has passed the very next second.

Instead, use something like [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), which returns seconds passed since the epoch:

```
def minute_passed(oldepoch):
    return time.time() - oldepoch >= 60
```

That can still be off by almost a second for the same reasons, but that's probably more acceptable.

Comment: The point is - its running ONCE per minute - if the minute ticks over a second after, thats okay. The rest of the script may take time from 5 - 25s depending on how long retrieving other data takes.

Answer (score 15):

You can use seconds since epoch to get the time in seconds so you don't have to worry about minutes wrapping around:

```
import time
oldtime = time.time()
# check
if time.time() - oldtime > 59:
    print "it's been a minute"
```

Answer (score 2):

I barely understand why nobody used `datetime` module here. This function should tell if it's same minute of same hour.

IMO it's pretty clear when your scheduled tasks starts at 0 second instead of random second and after each 60 seconds

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def is_new_minute(dt_old: datetime) -> bool:
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    return dt_now - dt_old > timedelta(minutes=1) or dt_now.minute != dt_old.minute
```

---

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = datetime.now()  # now=datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 23, 11, 8, 6, 538826)
    old_more_than_min = now - timedelta(minutes=2)  # old_more_than_min=datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 23, 11, 6, 6, 538826)
    old_less_than_min = now - timedelta(seconds=2)  # old_less_than_min=datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 23, 11, 8, 4, 538826)
    is_new_minute(old_more_than_min)  # True
    is_new_minute(old_less_than_min)  # False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find it much easier to use the `time()` function in the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module, which returns the number of seconds elapsed since the 'epoch'.

```
import time

oldtime = time.time()

def minutePassed(oldtime):
    currenttime = time.time()
    if currenttime - oldtime > 60 and ran == False:
        ran = True
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [time.sleep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    # do something
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: Not possible - this is just part of a script I run once a minute - its not the only thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had not much success with timedelta so I went with my former crude idea:

```
def minutePassed(oldminute):
    currentminute = time.gmtime()[4]

    if ((currentminute - oldminute) >= 1) or (oldminute == 59 and currentminute == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then in the script:

```
while True:
    dosomething()

    if minutePassed(time.gmtime(lastrun)[4]):
        domore
        lastrun = time.time()
```

This works perfectly fine for me now - only runs once a Minute - sleeping or anything is a bad choice for me here since the execution time on each loop is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I think I found a solution:

```
import time


oldtime = time.time()
print oldtime

while oldtime + 60 != time.time():

    if oldtime + 3 == time.time():
        print "60 secs passed"
        print time.time()
        break
```

You can delete the print statements, I had them there just to see if it works, hope it's what you are looking for.