# Run function after some time while other runs too

Tags: python, time, schedule

I need two things to happen: 1) something to happen continuously; 2) something to happen when the time comes, it's in the likes of:

```
while True:
    print('nothing happening')
    if 5_seconds_passed:
       print('five seconds passed')
```

I want the output to be like:

```
...
nothing happening
nothing happening
nothing happening
nothing happening
five seconds passed
nothing happening
nothing happening
...
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want 5 seconds to pass you could just in the loop before running the rest of your code

```
def 5_seconds_passed(oldepoch):
    return time.time() - oldepoch >= 5
```

where oldepoch is the time when it last run (set before the while loop begins)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000068/python-check-if-a-minute-has-passed/16000131)

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: If you find a similar answer, do not repost it.

Comment: @DYZ I try not to but how would I link to a similar answer? in the comments? or close the answer because of a similar answer (because I don't have those privileges)

Comment: Yes, and then someone with a higher reputation will mark this question as a duplicate.